# Adding a layer of plywood on top of subfloor for LVP install. Will the new layer help level the floor?

Tags: subfloor, vinyl-flooring

I am renovating my bathroom and originally planned to install cement board and porcelain tile for the flooring. I have 2x8 wood joists, 16" OC, with a span of 14'. I backtracked on the tile when I found my joists deflection is L/200 (the wife wanted to use large format tile and doesn't like any of the smaller tile options) so I am going with LVP (luxury vinyl plank) for the flooring. I using [this LVP](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lifeproof-Vesinet-Oak-22-mil-x-8-7-in-W-x-48-in-L-Click-Lock-Waterproof-Luxury-Vinyl-Plank-Flooring-20-1-sq-ft-case-IT7101702L/325477213).

I had removed the previous tile floor (some tiles were cracked) so there are a lot of holes left behind from the backerboard screws. In addition, there was mold damage so I had to replace a section of the subfloor. My plywood subfloor is 5/8" actual thickness which I couldn't find so I had to settle on [5/8" thick nominal plywood](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/panel-products/plywood-sheathing/5-8-x-4-x-8-plywood-sheathing/1231166/p-1444431331853-c-13331.htm) which is ~1/16" thinner than the existing plywood.

My question is whether or not adding an additional 5/8" nominal layer of plywood would help in covering all the screw holes in the subfloor and bring the patched subfloor section up to level (applying a generous amount of adhesive prior, hoping that levels out the 1/16" gap).

Another reason I was thinking to add another layer of plywood was to raise the floor height. If I don't raise the floor, there will be a gap between the LVP and the door jam. Additionally, the plumber set the toilet flange raised up about 3/8" from the subfloor and I don't think I can set the toilet down onto the flange if it isn't flush to the floor.

I appreciate any advice you may have.

Comment: A) The screw holes (unless they're from 3/4" bolts, and even then it's questionable) will be totally immaterial to the installation of LVP of any type. It'll glide over a screw hole without even noticing. B) Applying a 5/8" sheet over the patched floor _might_ be sufficient, but without knowing how big the patch is, it's impossible for us to say. A small spot, the new flooring might span it no problem, a full sheet, not so much.

Comment: I won't worry so much about the screw holes then. The patch is about a 3'x4' section so it is a pretty decent size. If I don't install another layer of plywood, I was thinking to use self-leveling concrete on the patch or using a few layers of felt paper to build the patch up to level.

Comment: Let's make sure you're using the term "level" correctly. In carpentry, it generally means _horizontal_. Is that what you're asking, or do you mean _smooth_ or _flat_?

Comment: 1/16" isn't a lot.  Why don't you just rip some 1/16" shims from 2x4 material and build up the joists so your new ply matches the existing ply?  you could also just use construction adhesive and 1/16" horseshoe shims before screwing down the ply.

Comment: Isherwood - yes, I mean level. There’s a 1/16” height difference between the existing plywood and the patched section.

Comment: Fresh Codemonger - if I could go back and do it again that would have been the best option. Everything is already installed and secured down